# converting image to bitmap in android

Tags: android, bitmap

i want to choose a picture from SD card of the mobile. i am using below code to choose and to display in my activity

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(selectedImagePath);
uploadimage.setImageURI(uri);
```

It is working fine, but I want to convert this image into `Bitmap`, I have image path and URI.

How to convert image to Bitmap in this case? Please help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Use this Link.. http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Working-With-Images-In-Android/2/

Comment: You can read about working with Bitmap here http://maximbogatov.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/bitmaps-in-android/ There is example how to get Bitmp from path.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use this code

```
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
```

Comment: awesome, glad you posted this.

Comment: needs a try catch block, but good answer

Answer (score -1):

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),uri);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: DEPREACATED ....